# How to create a group chat icon comprised of the users in the group icons photo (a collage of the users in the group)

Tags: dart, flutter

In flutter how would you create an icon for a group chat by stitching the photos of the users in the group into one collage style icon similar to that of facebook or snapchat? For example, Like this image but instead of the users initials, it would be their user photo:

[image: icon](https://imgur.com/p61N[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGHS.jpg)XMJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something more or less like this:

[image: example]

If so, all you need is a circle decorated `Container` with a `Column` that is clipped to it and has two `Expanded` rows with your avatars (I'm using the colored containers in its place).

You can define the radius of the container (circle) and the avatars will resize accordingly (at 50% each).

However, have in mind that this doesn't respect aspect ratio (you can check `AspectRatio`) since I don't know that if that's what you are looking for. `Wrap` widgets as suggested may work too, however, I find using `Flex` widgets more suitable for this scenarios.

```
class GroupAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final double _containerRadius = 300.0;

Widget _buildAvatar(double avatarRadius, Color color) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: color,
        height: avatarRadius,
        width: avatarRadius,
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double avatarRadius = _containerRadius * 0.5;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: _containerRadius,
            width: _containerRadius,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: ClipOval(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildAvatar(avatarRadius, Colors.green),
                      _buildAvatar(avatarRadius, Colors.blue),
                      _buildAvatar(avatarRadius, Colors.black),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildAvatar(avatarRadius, Colors.yellow),
                      _buildAvatar(avatarRadius, Colors.red),
                      _buildAvatar(avatarRadius, Colors.orange),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This involves use flutter layout.
(P.s The image provided has an invalid link)
You could try this

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flow Layout Flutter')),
    body: Center(
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.teal,
        child: Flow(
        delegate: SampleFlowDelegate(),
        children: <Widget>[
            buildItem(0),
            buildItem(1),
            buildItem(2),
            buildItem(3),
            buildItem(4),
            buildItem(5),
            buildItem(6),
        ],
        ),
     ),
   ),
);
```

or

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('AH')),
      label: Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('ML')),
      label: Text('Lafayette'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('HM')),
      label: Text('Mulligan'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('JL')),
      label: Text('Laurens'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

In your case you could add the image widget programmatically.

Comment: I have updated the image, would your code work for something like this?